# Does AngularJS differentiate between Model and ViewModel and their purpose?

Tags: angularjs

As AngularJS is MVC it seems every object holding data or logic is a model. But what about object not bound to the scope? which are sent to the server and their directly persisted into the database?

I am moving the whole business logic of my app from the web server (c#) to clientside because It just does not make sense to keep it on the server if I have already lots of javascript code.

My server side is just a thin web api with entity framework for the DB not more.

Now I ask myself how I should treat/name my objects not bound to the UI but used to calculate things I get from the UI.

Does angularjs somehow help here? Like naming conventions etc...?

**UPDATE with more details**

As Angularjs is a MVC framework should I use viewmodels at all using already models to be MVC conform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is "model agnostic" in that it doesn't force you to use any model implementation. You can put anything on your scope and bind templates and inputs to it. And that's a good thing, because it lets you choose a model implementation like Restangular or persistence.js.

So since Angular doesn't really care, it's all up to you. Angular doesn't help you with it, but it doesn't get in the way either.

We use persistence.js for a project and it's working nicely. Angular doesn't know and doesn't care that we use it, but it works really well. But we don't put our persistence.js models directly on the scope, but create special view models instead. So some typical code in our project would look like:

```
var customer = new model.Customer();
$scope.customer = customer.toViewModel();

$scope.save = function() {
  var customer = $scope.customer.toModel();
  persistence.add(customer);
  persistence.flush();
};
```

We've extended persistence.js to add the `toViewModel()` and `toModel()` methods, which basically just takes all properties and copies them to an anonymous object, and then back.

The reason we don't put our models directly on the scope is because persistence.js flushes all changes to all models when you call persistence.flush(), and if we bind directly to the models, some changes that the user didn't want to save might get saved. Another reason is that you never want your real model to be in an incorrect state, but it's okey for a view model to be in an incorrect state. It's up to the user to fix that when she's done.

So I'm not sure if I've answered your question, but it's up to you. Find a model library you like, or create your own that fits your needs.

Comment: Your answer already goes in the right direction. But you are in the lucky situation that you are forced by persistence.js to separate models from viewmodel. So you have not to make an architectural decision here.

Comment: Well, I would probably do that anyway. Since Javascript is highly dynamic, copying all properties to a new object (view model) is just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: I have also realized that I need both on client side because I can not pass a viewmodel to the server which expects models to persist or DTO`s but not viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

services, controllers and directives are the terms to google for you.

Maybe take a look at [Scalable code organization in AngularJS](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/9f01b594bf06) too.

hope i could help,

greetings